# Calculate RTP (Return to player) probability in the special game

Tags: probability

I'm working on a special game. Need to calculate correct RTP to make game profitable for the provider.
*Game description:*
Select the `win amount` and the `chance of winning`. Pay `required bet amount` to play current game. Press "play" button and get the `win amount` or loose `required bet amount`.
*Example of the one game:*

1. Selected `win amount` is 100 coins
2. Selected `chance of winning` is 50%
3. Depending on the `chance of winning` and `win amount`, game calculates `required bet amount`. In my current case, this amount is 50 coins.
4. You pay 50 coins to start the game and depending on the `chance of winnig` you can win `win amount`, or loose the game. So if you win, you got 100 coins - 50 coins = 50 coins.

I think, the chances would not be profitable for the game provider. How to make RTP 90%? What formula should I use to calculate the `required bet amount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the win amount is $w$, the chance of winning is $p$ and the required bet amount is $b$. If I understood correctly, you want that on average a player gets back 90% of what he bets.

The average gain is $(w-b)p-(1-p)b$, so we need to solve $(w-b)p-(1-p)b=0.9b$, which yields $(0.9+1-p+p)b=wp$, i.e. $b=\frac{wp}{1.9}$

Comment: Can you please show the example of this formula usage?

Comment: I don't know "b" value, only "w" and "p" is known

Comment: @user14080657 I'm not sure what you mean, in your example this would be $b=\frac{wp}{1.9}=\frac{100*0.5}{1.9}$

Comment: @user14080657 yeah, that's why I'm computing $b$ as a function of $w$ and $p$